# VB .Net - Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Form.resx

Tags: vb.net, winforms

After converting a project from .Net Framework 4 to 2, can't build the project because of an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on "MyForm.resx" file.

This file isn't visible in the solution explorer.

When you look at the file, the error is shown at the first line, which is just an xml.

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was to open the form, in designer view, and actually move around some control or other, and the move it back to place.

This causes visual studio to re-save the file, making the following changes to the resx:

```
<resheader name="reader">
<value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=(old value-->)4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
<value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=(new value-->)2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
```